# How to test if PowerBI schedule refresh is working?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I setup a schedule refresh for several reports according to Microsoft documentation.

However, some of the reports may require at least daily update and I cannot wait till next day to see if it works.  It is too slow.

So I would like to ask if there are any way in the powerbi.com website to test if schedule refresh works?

Thank you very much in advance for all your help.

**Updated on 24/7:**

First of all thanks for all comments and responses.

Here is what I want to do:

**I want to refresh the dataset manually**, so that if it works perfectly, I can believe that the schedule refresh will also work fine.

However, the "Refresh Now" button in dataset mentioned by @Andrey seems only refresh the cache version of the data, not the latest data.

Because it said "Cache Refresh History":
[image: Cache refresh history, not real time data history]

While the status said it is "Completed", actually it is not.  The data is not updated at all.

That's why I want a "Real-time Data update" button that runs the same process as schedule refresh.

Thank you very much in advance for all your help.

Comment: Are you looking for the option of checking and refreshing a data set manually? This is available in Power BI service and you can check details like Refresh history or Run a manual Refresh after login.

Answer (score 1):

First, an e-mail will be sent in case of refresh failure. Make sure the checkbox `Send refresh failure notifications to dataset owner` is selected (assuming you are the dataset owner) when configuring the scheduled refresh. You can also [specify additional recipients](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/sending-refresh-notifications-to-others/) for these notifications.

[image]

You can also check the refresh history of a dataset(s) using [Get Refresh History](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/getrefreshhistory) and [Get Refresh History In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/getrefreshhistoryingroup) APIs. For example with the following PowerShell script you can get information about the last 3 refreshes of particular dataset and do some automation in case of failure:

```
Import-Module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt
Import-Module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt.Profile

$password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$username = "xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxx.com" 
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)

Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -Credential $credential

$response = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url 'groups/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/datasets/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/refreshes?$top=3' -Method Get

$response_json = ConvertFrom-Json $response

# Write-Output $response_json

$response_json.value | ForEach-Object { Write-Output "Status: $($_.Status) , Time completed: $($_.endTime)" }

Disconnect-PowerBIServiceAccount
```

If you want to trigger a refresh of the dataset instead, change the method of the API call above to be `Post`.

From Power BI Service site, you can manually refresh a dataset from the workspace view for example:

[image]

or go to dataset's settings to see its refresh history:

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  But no, it is not what I want.  I want something like a button that can trigger the schedule refresh manually so that everything is alright.  When everything is going fine, I can rest assured that no problem will occur in coming days.

Comment: From dataset settings you can refresh the dataset manually. This is the button that you are looking for. Or you want a PowerShell script that you can execute to trigger the refresh?

Comment: Please update your question that this is what you want, I will delete my answer.

Comment: Hi all.  Thank you and question is updated.  Hope it makes things clear.